# build.gradle dependencies missing

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, build.gradle

I've never really started a project requiring external dependencies from start, so bear with me.

I'm trying to get my project setup so I can start development, but whenever I try to run the gradlew command `gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse`, my dependencies don't seem to come in as I get this build for all depdencies:

```
Project 'ProjectName' is missing required library: 'projectPath\ProjectName\unresolved dependency - org.apache.tomcat tomcat 8.0.29'
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.0.RELEASE")
    }
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'idea'

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat:8.0.29'

    compile 'org.springframework:spring-beans:4.2.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.2.3.RELEASE'
}
```

Am I missing something? Am I not running gradle correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build configuration will work just fine if you'll provide a repositories for the project too, because now it's done just for the build script. Try to add:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

into your build script root. And then you just have to update a dependencies in your IDE possibly. Tried it with gradle 2.8 and IntelliJIdea.

But, you've applied `spring-boot-gradle-plugin` though your project doesn't seem to be spring-boot project. If you want to use spring-boot, you need to depend on

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
```

or some other spring-boot-starter libraries. This one above, for example, will provide an embedded tomcat within. Otherwise, you don't need to have a

```
classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.0.RELEASE")
```

in the build.script dependencies.

Furthermore, you don't need to apply 'java' plugin, since you have a 'war' plugin applied, because `war` extends `java`.

Comment: I added the `mavenCentral` repository to the root and removed the spring-boot compile and it can build now. Thanks!